# AS3 how to access nested arrays from xml?

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, nested

I am having problem with 2d nested arrays, I want to create one which is coming from XML.
My Xml(‘test.xml’) looks like this:

```
<content>
<item image="Mike.jpg" name="Mike" state = "New York">
 <complex fid = "0"> ju675</complex>
 <complex fid = "1"> kyu49</complex>
</item>

<item image="John.jpg" name="John" state = "New Jersey" >
 <complex fid = "0"> mg749</complex>
 <complex fid = "1"> ks749</complex>
 <complex fid = "2"> ks678</complex>
    </item>

<item image="Smith.jpg" name="Smith" state = "California">
 <complex fid = "0"> we649</complex>
 <complex fid = "1"> sd449</complex>
 <complex fid = "2"> df459</complex>
 <complex fid = "3"> hj569</complex>
    </item>
</content>
```

And here is the AS3 code i am using, i want to use only this method of creating nested array, i am pretty sure ia m doing something wrong, but not sure where.

```
 var level:Array = [];
 var complexes:Array = [];
 loadXML();
 function loadXML():void
 {
     var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
     loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeXMLHandler);
     var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest('test.xml');
     try
     {
         loader.load(request);
     }
     catch(error:Error)
     {
         trace('Impossible to load the document.');
     }
 }

function completeXMLHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader=URLLoader(event.target);
    var result:XML=new XML(loader.data);
    var myXML:XMLDocument=new XMLDocument();
    myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
    myXML.parseXML(result.toXMLString());

    for each (var usr in result.item)
    {
        level.push({name:usr.@name,state:usr.@state,complex:usr.item,state:usr.@image});
    }

    for ( var row:int = 0; row < level.length; row++ )
    {
        trace(level[row].name);
        for ( var column:int = 0; column < level[row].length; column++ )
        {
            trace(level[row][column].complex);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: As a bit of a side note: make sure you properly indent code (I fixed your example). It makes it easier to read (and therefore more likely to get a reply) and I'm pretty sure that in some circles violation of that rule is a hangable offense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to let us know what you're seeing and what you want to see, but here are some issues I would fix:

Don't use XMLDocument. That's a holdover from an earlier version of ActionScript. You should only use XML and XMLList (XMLListCollection is available in Flex).

You don't want to use parseXML either (especially since you already have an iterable object).  `var items:XMLList = result.children( "item" )` will give you a list of all of the item nodes in your results.  You'll then be able to replace `var usr in result.item` with `var usr:XML in items`.

In this line:

```
var usr in result.item
```

type your variable.

In this line:

```
level.push({name:usr.@name,state:usr.@state,complex:usr.item,state:usr.@image});
```

the usr object will not have an item property.  If you want the node itself, set complex to the value of usr.

This line:

```
trace(level[row][column].complex);
```

will give you unexpected results. The `complex` property is XML. You want to call `toXMLString()`.

Comment: thanx for replying. I am not good in as3 but all i wanted to do is,create 2d array, so for ex I want to access name, state and complex by Level[row][column].state, Level[row][column].complex...is it possible?